# How do I know if I use GCM at all?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Just got an email from Firebase that I need to migrate from GCM to FCM.
How can I find if I'm using GCM at all on my android apps?
I know I'm using OneSignal for web push notifications and Airbop for the app notifications.

Comment: If you are using `gradle`to load your dependencies then you should be able to see if GCM is used--you will see something like "com.google.gms:google-services...." if you are using FCM you will see something like "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you've implemented anything mentioned in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). If you can't see anything familiar, then you should be fine. If you're using OneSignal (or any other service at this matter), either they would implement the change on their end (if they are using GCM for their service) and advise you to apply anything if you need to. Besides that, I think the email was sent to all Firebase users or Google API users in general.

Comment: Thanks, I found that my Airbop configuration is already on Firebase.